# Django Rest Framework Generic Relationships and ViewSets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model Comment that can go on either Project or Task.

```
class Comment(BaseCommentModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
            ContentType,
            verbose_name=_('content type'),
            related_name="contenttype_set_for_%(class)s"
    )
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

Project and Task have the field set up as:

```
comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

Comments can be created on either Projects or Tasks so there should be a viewset for each:

```
class ProjectCommentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

class TaskCommentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
```

And those would display the comments related to each model.

But what I don't understand is:

1. How do I set up the create/update/delete in a viewset for the Comment model so that the comment is created with the correct relationship?
2. How do I filter inside the viewsets to display comments related to that model?  I can't use select_related because the Comment doesn't have a Project or Task field.
3. How do I write the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`s for these relationships?  Do I need to add a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` to CommentSerializer() and then `HyperlinkedRelatedField`s to the User, Project, and Task Serializers?  Or how do I set this up?

Thanks for any help provided, I could really use some direction here.

I'm having trouble understanding how the relationships on the models translate to the serializers and viewsets.  And also how to handle the relationships when using generic relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.  This will return an list of id's, which is what you would use for a create/update for a `Project` model instance with related `Comment` records.

Other than that, `GenericRelation` behaves just like other ORM relationships within `django-rest-framework`.

In the `ViewSet` `Serializer` define it like so:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, serializers

class ProjectCommentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Comment.objects.all(), many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'etc...', 'comments',)
```

Comment: Would I need to define fields for content_type object_id and content_object in comment serializer?

Comment: No, those are only needed in the `model` definition.